# SAPUI5 application checking for Virus scan profile in Gateway

Tags: sapui5, abap

Scratching my head with the following problem.
I have developed a SAPUI5 application using smarttemplates/odata annotations. In the first screen - i create entries for an entity - navigate to another screen - create entries for another entity - pretty simple.

But the problem is, I am encountering an error Virus scan profile   not active in the backend (gateway embedded). When I switch off the virus profile in /n/IWFND/VIRUS_SCAN backend, all good . No issues at all.

But switch on to a default profile, back comes the problem. 90% of the times I get it in the second screen, but 10% in the first entity.

The weird part is, all the other UI5 applications in the same system works ! If it's a system problem, then it has to be affecting all the ones, but only my application is stuck with this problem.

I realize that there is something different between mine and the rest, but I am unable to figure out what it is . I have compared the projects, manifest/project.json, etc. $batch request payload of mine vs. others and I see no anomaly, other than the _changeset, rest all are identical, and adhering.

So, what would be the one thing that is making a POST request from my application trigger the check for virus scan profile and fail ? 
Even strange is, the request statuscode is 202 , but it doesn't reach the backend at all.

Any help is highly appreciated,

thanks,
Sathish R

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the issue seems that one of the properties in my entity is of type EDM.Guid, one of the types for which a virus scan would be performed before passing through the request. As we don't have any profiles configured, I ended up with the error. Converting it to string just fixed the issue :-)

thanks,
Sathish R

Comment: You can accept your own answer to let others know that the issue is resolved now